# Apple Pay with iPhone 6

Tags: iphone

Does Apple Pay require password unlock protection on the iPhone?  I know I am a party of one for feeling this way, but having to use the password unlock routine is just too cumbersome for the immediate use of my phone.  Please don't slam me over the virtues of it's use, or the idiocy of not using it. I just want to know if it can be eliminated to use Apple Pay.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a passcode to use Apple Pay. This is because every transaction with Apple Pay is authenticated by you by using your Touch ID or passcode.

You can't use touch ID without a passcode, so there is no way around this.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple Pay uses touchID](https://www.apple.com/apple-pay/) so you don't need to use a password.

Comment: I believe you will still have to enter the password once, every time the device is rebooted from a full shutdown (not just turned "off", only when the apple logo is shown starting up) or an iOS update is installed.

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to set a passcode, if the phone doesn't already have one, when setting up Touch ID.